# Evaluating constant when creating dictionary keys

Tags: javascript, typescript

```
const myKey: string = 'something'

const myDict: { [id: string]: string } = {
  myKey: 'some value',
}
```

and I would like the dictionary to look like:

```
{ 'something' : 'some value' }
```

but the actual result is:

```
{ myKey : 'some value' }
```

How can I force the constant to be replaced by its value when creating the dictionary?

Comment: Yes, ECMAScript computed values are perfect! `{ [myKey]: 'some value' }` Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it the following way using ES6 computed property names:

```js
const myKey = 'something';
const myDict = {[myKey]: 'some value'};

console.log(myDict);
```

More about **computed property names** can be found here - https://eloquentcode.com/computed-property-names-in-javascript